# Bootstrap center-block is not centering image

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have added the class `center-block`  to be able to vertical center the Torza image. But no result, any suggestions?

[image]

```
<?php
<div class="container">
    <hr />
        <div class="text-center center-block">
                <a href="https://torza.nl" target="_blank"><img src="img/logo_torza.png" alt="Torza" width="85"></a>
                <a href="https://torza.nl" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-2x social"></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/torza/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/torzanl" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                <a href="mailto:info@torza.nl"><i class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
        </div>
    <hr />
    </div>
?>
```

Comment: `center-block` is used to horizontally center something, also provide your CSS please

Comment: Can you add your css and the link to your image

Comment: Plz show the css used with this html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <hr />
        <div class="torza-box">
              <a href="https://torza.nl" target="_blank"><img src="img/logo_torza.png" alt="Torza" width="85"></a>
              <div class="links-box">
                   <a href="https://torza.nl" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-2x social"></i></a>
                   <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/torza/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/torzanl" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                   <a href="mailto:info@torza.nl"><i class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-2x social"></i></a></div>
           </div>
    <hr />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.torza-box{
   position:relative;
}

.links-box{
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   right:10px;
   transform:translatey(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you added bootstrap CSS URL then this work as good, otherwise you write simple CSS code here...**

```
.center-block a {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

or view [jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sayed021/y44cgfdL/)

**Thank you**

Answer (score -2):

Don't add it as a class, in that div tag use this:

```
<div style="text-align:center, margin-left:auto, margin-right:auto>
```

and i'm not sure why this is in php tags, this won't work with html unless you're echoing it.

Either get rid of the php tags or at the beginning write `echo"` and at the end write `";`

Either replace it with this:

```
<?php
echo"
<div class="container">
    <hr />
        <div class="text-center center-block">
                <a href="https://torza.nl" target="_blank"><img src="img/logo_torza.png" alt="Torza" width="85"></a>
                <a href="https://torza.nl" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-2x social"></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/torza/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/torzanl" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                <a href="mailto:info@torza.nl"><i class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
        </div>
    <hr />
</div>
";
?>
```

or just get rid of the `<?php?>` tags